# Using YEAR function in MAXIFS criteria in excel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, criteria, maxifs

I have a following spreadsheet, which contains the timestamp, a numerical result, and the time (duration) took to calculate the result.

[image]

From this I need to calculate maximum value of Duration in 2019

I tried something like this, but the function YEAR is not supported on the MAXIFS.

```
MAXIFS(B3:B100, YEAR(A3:A100), 2019)
```

Is there a way to do it using MAXIFS, or if there's a better way to do it using built-in methods. I want to avoid using Macros.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried a helper column to get just the year based on the date?

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, and then it will be really easy to use MAXIFS. Thanks for providing the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have "Duration" in column C, therefor try:

```
=MAXIFS(C3:C100,A3:A100,">="&DATE(2019,1,1),A3:A100,"<"&DATE(2020,1,1))
```

With Microsoft365, you may try:

```
=MAX(FILTER(C3:C100,YEAR(A3:A100)=2019))
```